# How to solve circular import + pydantic error when using strongly related classes?

Tags: python, fastapi, circular-dependency, pydantic

I'm trying to separate two schemas, following a 'module' folder structure for my FastAPI app. But doing so causes a circular import error. I made a simpler version of the app to isolate the issue, only using fastapi and uvicorn to start it.

The folder structure is like this, `__init__.py`'s ommited

```
src/
  users/
    schemas.py
  posts/
    schemas.py
  main.py
```

```py
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

from .users.schemas import User

app = FastAPI()

@router.get("/", response_model=list[User])
def get_users():
    return []


# users/schemas.py
from pydantic import BaseModel

from ..posts.schemas import Post

class User(BaseModel):
    posts: list[Post]


# posts/schemas.py
from pydantic import BaseModel

from ..users.schemas import User

class Post(BaseModel):
    users: list[User]
```

---

I have tried multiple solutions in various sites and tried ChatGPT, and so far I can't avoid circular import errors without having pydantic complaining with `pydantic.errors.PydanticUndefinedAnnotation: name 'Post' is not defined`.

Gives circular import error:

- Using string form (e.g. list['User'])

Gives pydantic error (basically any forward referencing method):

- Using TypeVar:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel
 
class User(BaseModel):
    posts: list[TypeVar("T", bound="Post")]

from ..posts.schemas import Post
```

- Using ForwardRef:

```py
from typing import ForwardRef
from pydantic import BaseModel

Post = ForwardRef("Post")

class User(BaseModel):
    posts: list[Post]

from ..posts.schemas import Post
```

The requirements.txt for this example, I'm using python 3.11.4

```
annotated-types==0.5.0
anyio==3.7.1
click==8.1.6
colorama==0.4.6
fastapi==0.100.0
h11==0.14.0
httptools==0.6.0
idna==3.4
pydantic==2.0.3
pydantic_core==2.3.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
PyYAML==6.0.1
sniffio==1.3.0
starlette==0.27.0
typing_extensions==4.7.1
uvicorn==0.23.1
watchfiles==0.19.0
websockets==11.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your imports itself is circular

first your **main** file gets loaded into the memory and this line gets executed

`from .users.schemas import User`

then the interpreter goes to `users.schema` location and starts reading it
as soon as it comes to this line

`from ..posts.schemas import Post`
tries executing it

interpreter executes the above line it moves to `post.schema` location

`from ..users.schemas import User`

where it encounters the above line and tries executing it and just like this you can see the loop it again goes to `users.schema` encounter the post import then comes to `post.schema` again ecnounters the user import keeps doing it until python raises circular import error.

if you have some sort of situation like this try keeping dependencies like this in the same level like in same file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'TYPE_CHECKING' functionality as suggested in the documentation?

https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/code-structure/